# how to save m3u8 stream

Tags: streaming, mp4

I want to save a m3u-stream. The content of the m3u8 files looks like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=756617,CODECS="avc1.77.31, mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x360
http://1.2.3.4/ipad/cms-worldwide/2013-12-08_1055_sd_02_some_name_Q4A.mp4?wowzasessionid=9999999999&publishingpoint=cms-worldwide&ip=6.6.6.6&ua=Mozilla%252f5.0%2b(Windows%2bNT%2b6.1%253b%2bWOW64%253b%2brv%253a25.0)%2bGecko%252f20100101%2bFirefox%252f25.0&origin=http%253a%252f%252f1.2.3.4%252fcms-worldwide%252f2013-12-08_1055_sd_02_some_name_Q4A.mp4%252fchunklist.m3u8%253fip%253d6.6.6.6%2526ua%253dMozilla%2525252f5.0%25252b(Windows%25252bNT%25252b6.1%2525253b%25252bWOW64%2525253b%25252brv%2525253a25.0)%25252bGecko%2525252f20100101%25252bFirefox%2525252f25.0
```

If I want to open the URL I always get the m3u-file ... How can I save the `mp4` file? I should mention that I don't want to buy a software for this ...

Answer (score 1):

You cant save the mp4. It is behind a wowza server. You can request the manifest, download all the segments, concatenate them to a single transport stream, then remux to mp4.